# El "espacio" está bloqueado en input

Tags: reactjs

les comento, el siguiente componente se encarga de  buscar datos que ya fueron obtenidos de la base de datos:

El problema es que no me deja utilizar espacios, por ejemplo quiero buscar "Silobolsa Pepe" y solamente me dejaria buscar asi "SilobolsaPepe"

Por lo que busqué, lo más probable es que sea por ésta linea: `onInputChange={(e: any) => setSearchValue(e.toUpperCase())}` que basicamente lo que hace es que todo lo que escriba, se envia en mayusculas, y por eso el "espacio" no está siendo reconocido.

Pero quería saber si se les ocurre alguna otra idea a ustedes, que tienen más experiencia.

```
  const SeachInput = (
    <Form>
      <div className="navBarInputSize">
        <Form.Group controlId="form-sil" className="input-search">
          <InputGroup hasValidation className="no-wrap">
            <Select
              className={"search-input-navbar"}
              placeholder="Buscar silo o lanza"
              components={{ DropdownIndicator, Control }}
              options={
                siloBagData.silobagList && siloBagData.silobagList.length > 0
                  ? siloBagData.silobagList
                      .filter((value: any) =>
                        searchValue === ""
                          ? false
                          : value.name.toUpperCase().indexOf(searchValue) > -1
                      )
                      .map((value: any) => ({
                        value,
                        label: value.name,
                      }))
                  : []
              }
              onInputChange={(e: any) => setSearchValue(e.toUpperCase())}
              onChange={(e: any) =>
                navigate(Paths.VIEW_SILO, {
                  state: {
                    from: path,
                    record: e.value,
                  },
                })
              }
            />
            <InputGroup.Text
              id="inputGroupPrepend"
              className={"navBarInputSearch"}
            >
              <Image style={{ height: "12.28", width: 13 }} src={SearchIcon} />
            </InputGroup.Text>
          </InputGroup>
        </Form.Group>
      </div>
    </Form>
  );
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Actualizacion:

El `Select` pertenece a la libreria react-select, ésta es la configuracion que tiene:

```
declare type StateManagedSelect = <Option = unknown, IsMulti extends boolean = false, Group extends GroupBase<Option> = GroupBase<Option>>(props: StateManagerProps<Option, IsMulti, Group> & RefAttributes<Select<Option, IsMulti, Group>>) => ReactElement;
declare const StateManagedSelect: StateManagedSelect;
export default StateManagedSelect;
```

Comment: `toUpperCase()` respeta los espacios, sugiero que muestres el codigo de `setSearchValue` y comparte un poco de la secuencia que hay en `options,` ¿Que hace esa pieza de código? Tambien se ve un `toUpperCase()` ahi...

Comment: @g.4 no sé si `options` tendrá algo que ver, lo quité del componente y no cambio absolutamente nada. Tampoco sirven los compandos como `mayus + inicio` o `mayus+fin ` para seleccionar toda la cadena. Será porque el componente es un   `Select ` ?

Comment: Por lo que vi, `Select` tiene la opcion isSearchable,  por lo que no creo que tampoco tenga que ver el `Select`

Comment: Por favor recuerdame este `Select` esta built in en react o es de una libreria? Se me ocurre que ese input debe ser controlado por react, tal cual se controla un `input`

Comment: @g.4 disculpame por tardar, el `Select` está importado de `"react-select"`: `import Select, { components } from "react-select";`

Comment: Actualicé la pregunta, muestro lo que tiene `Select`